# Having trouble understanding C++ streams

Tags: c++, stream

I have to read some data from an input stream, run it through some filters, and then display the context on screen. I'm working with Windows and currently stuck on this. I'm having a hard time understanding the I/O streams.

I don't know what I should do after passing the data through the first filter because currently, the second function calculates 0 chars?

**main:**

```
std::ifstream data("somedata.txt");
whitesprem(data);
calc_chars(data);
```

**whitesprem:**

```
    // removes extra white spaces

    void whitesprem(std::ifstream& fff) {
        std::string line;

        while(std::getline(fff, line)){
          std::regex rgx("\\s{2,}");
          line = std::regex_replace(line, rgx, " ")
          //How to move on?
       }    
   }
```

Comment: If you want to filter characters from a stream you should be looking at the `streambuf` classes. The `stream` derived classes don't have the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: To expand a little on the above. `stream` derived classes wrap `streambuf` derived classes. All the `stream` classes really do is wrap a different `streambuf` derived classes and provide a number of higher level I/O methods. The actual low level I/O is done by the `streambuf` derived class. So if you want to write a filtered stream, the way to do it is to write a `streambuf` derived class to do the filtering. Then you can have a chain of `streambuf` derived classes each doing some operation (filtering, transforming or whatever), until the final `streambuf` in the chain does the actual I/O.

Comment: Finally you write a `stream` derived class that wraps the first `streambuf` in your chain to provide the familar higher level I/O operations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consume each line inside your `whiteprem()`. Another approach could be to just copy the data to another string stream from the file stream and use the new stream in the rest of the program.

Probably you intend to do something like this:

```cpp
void whiteprem(std::ifstream& ff, std::stringstream &update){
std::string line;

        while(std::getline(fff, line)){
          std::regex rgx("\\s{2,}");
          line = std::regex_replace(line, rgx, " ")
          //How to move on?
          update << line << std::endl;
       }

}
int main(){
  std::ifstream data("somedata.txt");
  std::stringstream ss;
  whitesprem(data, ss);
  calc_chars(ss);
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks! You also said that one way could be to "consume" each line. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Like, use the `line` string to calculate the character length within `whiteprem()` method. Perhaps, may not be a good idea if your `calc_chars` is a big function.